# Misaligned in the environment proof

Tags: proofreading

After changing the theme (the theme is "berlin") of my presentation in the beamer. My proof environment is totally misaligned. Below is my header

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \usepackage[portuges]{babel}
    \usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{esint}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{yfonts}
    \usepackage{eulervm}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usetheme[secheader]{Berlin}
    \usecolortheme{seahorse}
    \useinnertheme{rounded}
    \useoutertheme{shadow}
    \usefonttheme{structurebold}
    \numberwithin{equation}{section}
    \setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]



    \newtheorem{Cor}{Corol\'ario}[section]
    \newtheorem{Prop}{Proposi\c c\~ao}[section]
    \newtheorem{Def}{Defini\c c\~ao}[section]
    \newtheorem{Teo}{Teorema}[section]
    \newtheorem{Lema}{Lema}[section]


    \title{blabla}
    \author{blablabla}
    \institute{blabla}
    \date{13/12/2017}

    \begin{document}
    \vspace{7cm}
    \frame{\begin{figure}[!h]
    \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{BrasaoUFC.jpg}
    \end{figure}\titlepage}



    \begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

ex:

[image]

generated by

```
\begin{frame}

\begin{proof} \noindent Temos que $\partial U \in C^{1}$ , então existe uma extensão $Eu=\bar{u} \in W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, tal que $\bar{u}=u$ em $U$,  $\bar{u}$ tem suporte compacto , e 

\begin{equation}
\parallel \bar{u}\parallel_{W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\leq C \parallel u \parallel_{W^{1,p}(U)}.  
\end{equation}

\noindent Agora como $\bar{u}$ suporte compacto existe $u_{m} \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ tal que $ u_{m}\to  u$  em ${W^{1,p}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$ e do lema $2.1$ $ u_{m}\to \bar{u}$ em ${L^{p*}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}$, novamente o lema $2.1$ e as duas últimas afirmações anteriores  junto com as propriedade da extensão dadas no início da prova completam a demonstração.

\end{proof}

\end{frame}
```

Any tips?
Thanks

Comment: First, your should add `\end{document}` at the end. I tried using your codes, but found nothing wrong. Could you give an effect figure?

Comment: Well, I guess in order prove your claim you need to add the proof. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe in the Berlin theme, all texts are flushed left in default. So if you want to make the texts justify align, you should, after the line of

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

add the codes

```
\justifying\let\raggedright\justifying
```